# use of array to skip specific sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to vba and I am trying to use vba code to check the sheet name from `Array` and if the name matches with the worksheet name than skip that sheet. However code doesn't work and it skips the sheets equal with the length of `Array`. Furthermore, is it possible to use "if-Then-else" with `Array`.

---

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim a As Long
Dim wsname As Variant

wsname = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")

For a = LBound(wsname) To UBound(wsname)
    wsname(a) = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate
Next a
```

---

Comment: Welcome to SO. *code doesn't work*  it's, probably, one of the worst ways to describe your problem.please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to go through your array I would suggest something like:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsname)
```

Or even directly:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5"))
```

It could look like below:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsname As Variant: wsname = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsname)
    If Not ws Is ActiveSheet Then
        'Do Something
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

However, working with `ActiveSheet` (and `.Activate` in your original post) is hardly ever needed, and never recommended!

Comment: Thank you for help.. it is really useful. I surely keep in mind your suggestion regarding Working with  `ActiveSheet`

Answer (score 2):

This code will go through the sheets in the array and list each sheet's name in the Immediate Window unless it's the ActiveSheet at the time of running the code.

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim a As Long
Dim WsName As Variant

WsName = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")

For a = LBound(WsName) To UBound(WsName)
    Set Ws = Worksheets(WsName(a))
    If Not Ws Is ActiveSheet Then
        Debug.Print Ws.Name
    End If
Next a
```

If the sheet doesn't exist and error will occur.